# WCFService calling a Singleton instance from windows service returning empty

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a static (large)data from database that i need to send to clients so i created a singleton class that get the data from the database and populate the list.
I start the service host inside the windows service, so when an outside call the wcf the data comes empty, what should i do?

```c#
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class CacheDataService : ICacheDataService
{
    public List<Sale> GetDataFromImobDateById(int idImob, DateTime date)
    {
        return SalesHelper.Instance.GetDataFromImobDate(idImob, date);
    }
}
public class SalesHelper
    {
        static Lazy<SalesHelper> singleton = new Lazy<SalesHelper>(() => new SalesHelper());
        public static SalesHelper Instance { get { return singleton.Value; } }
        ICacheData<Sale> _cache;
        List<Sale> CacheData = new List<Sale>();
        public void SetCache(ICacheData<Sale> cacheData)
        {
            _cache = cacheData;
        }
        public void ReloadCache()
        {
            CacheData.Clear();
            GetAllData();
        }
        public void GetAllData()
        {
            CacheData = _cache.GetAllData();
        }

        public List<Sale> GetDataFromImobDate(int idImob, DateTime date)
        {
            var result = (from r in CacheData
                          where r.Data_Alteracao.Equals(date)
                          && r.Id_Imobiliaria.Equals(idImob)
                          select r).ToList();
            return result;
        }
}
```

and in the Service i start the ServiceHost and the cache

```c#
_tempSales = new SalesHelper();
ICacheData<Sale> _cacheSale = new Sale();
_tempSales.SetCache(_cacheSale);
_tempSales.GetAllData();
_service = new ServiceHost(typeof(CacheDataService));
```

Comment: Could you add SalesHelper  class too please?

Comment: Sorry, i put the wrong class name. Already corrected.

Comment: One more question: where are you using this method `GetDataFromImobDateById`? This is where the data comes empty, right? Why am I asking that? `_tempSales` is being initialized with its respective cache, that's ok. But `SalesHelper.Instance` has never been set...

Comment: From the client where i reference the wcf. Also i don´t need to set the instance, right, it´s already setted as the value of the _singleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are missing the initialization of `SalesHelper.Instance`.
doing this `new Lazy<SalesHelper>(() => new SalesHelper());` leads to get an intance of `_cache` not initialized.

So we have a couple of workaround to chose.
One of them is initilize the Intance:

```
SalesHelper.Instance.SetCache(_cacheSale);
```

It should look like this:

```
//_tempSales = new SalesHelper();
ICacheData<Sale> _cacheSale = new Sale();
//_tempSales.SetCache(_cacheSale);
//_tempSales.GetAllData();
SalesHelper.Instance.SetCache(_cacheSale);
SalesHelper.Instance.GetAllData(); //Now it should return the info
_service = new ServiceHost(typeof(CacheDataService));
```

The other one is replace your prop `Intance` with a factory method `GetInstance()` which should receive the cache and set it if it is needed.

Let me know if the first workaround solve your problem.

Comment: Oh, i´m testing right now, but it makes sense. What i was doing was completely wrong.